# Why do I need semicolons after these imports?

Tags: scala, import, traits

I never really used Traits much in Scala so far, and I want to change this. I have this code:

```
import tools.nsc.io.Path
import java.io.File

trait ImageFileAcceptor extends FileAcceptor {
    override def accept(f:File) =  {
        super.accept(f) match {
            case true => {
                // additional work to see if it's really an image
            }
            case _ => false
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I compile with `sbt`, I keep receiving:

`ImageFileAcceptor.scala:2: ';' expected but 'import' found.`

If I add `;` after the imports, the code compiles. Here's `FileAcceptor`:

```
import java.io.File

trait FileAcceptor extends Acceptable {
    override def accept(f:File):Boolean = f.isFile
}
```

And here's `Acceptable`:

```
import java.io.File

trait Acceptable {
    def accept(f:File):Boolean
}
```

I don't understand why I need semicolons after the imports.

Maybe the output of sbt is helpful:

```
[info] Building project tt 1.0 against Scala 2.8.1
[info]    using sbt.DefaultProject with sbt 0.7.5 and Scala 2.7.7
```

Comment: When I add "true" after "// additional work to see if it's really an image", it compiles fine with fsc under Scala 2.9.0 RC1.

Comment: On my computer I have true there. I only wanted to shorten the snippet.

Comment: This could be a line ending issue - did you maybe accidentally save your file with old Macintosh line endings (\r)? That actually produces exactly the error you are seeing.

Comment: Incredible voodoo debugging! Though I have no idea how the ending got to be in Macintosh format. Please add an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the scala compiler encounters a Macintosh line ending--being `\r`--the scala compiler will erroneously declare the need for a semi-colon, as Moritz so deduced. Section 1.2 of the [Scala Reference Manual](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) describe correct newline characters. I could not find in the Reference which character literals were considered as newlines. From experience, both Windows (`\r\n`) and Unix (`\n`) are acceptable. Presumably scala is strictly compatible with Java in this regard.