# ';' expected but 'import' found - Scala and Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, compiler-errors, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to work with Spark and Scala, compiling a standalone application. I don't know why I'm getting this error:

```
topicModel.scala:2: ';' expected but 'import' found.
[error] import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.LDA
[error] ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

This is the build.sbt code:

```
name := "topicModel"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.3.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-graphx" % "1.3.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "1.3.1"
```

And those are the imports:

```
import scala.collection.mutable
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.LDA
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

object Simple {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
```

Comment: Are you sure that there are no weird characters at the end of the first line?

Answer (score 0):

This could be because your file has old Macintosh line endings (\r)?

See [Why do I need semicolons after these imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748451/why-do-i-need-semicolons-after-these-imports) for more details.