# 1: error: ';' expected but 'import' found

Tags: pyspark

I am running this code in Zeppelin, I am getting following error message

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext

sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonSQL")
hive_context = HiveContext(sc)

bank = hive_context.table("default.invites_orc")
bank.show()
bank.registerTempTable("bank_temp")
hive_context.sql("select * from bank_temp").show()
sc.stop()
```

:1: error: ';' expected but 'import' found.
       from pyspark import SparkContext 
                    ^

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422750/expected-but-import-found-scala-and-spark

Answer (score 0):

The Spark Interpreter group currently has 4 interpreter as listed here...

https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/docs/0.5.0-incubating/interpreter/spark.html

The default interpreter is %spark and default interpreter is selected based on the order of the interpreter listed in the zeppelin.interpreters property in zeppelin-site.xml config file.

The current order of interpreter in your zeppelin-site.xml (zeppelin.interpreters property) will be this ...

org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter,org.apache.zeppelin.spark.PySparkInterpreter
Modify this to ...

org.apache.zeppelin.spark.PySparkInterpreter, org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter
and restart Zeppelin (zeppelin-daemon.sh restart)

This will make %pyspark as default interpreter.

OR

You can write like this

```
%pyspark

from pyspark import SparkContext
```